# Concatenation of multiple .csv files not giving required result on python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system, glob

I have a total of 24 .csv files each having 3 columns and a number of rows (15677 to be exact which are split in these 24 files) containing the data that I require to read.
I would like to access and read these data files in chronological order.
At first I tried to concatenate these files but for some reason I am obtaining a matrix that has [15653 rows x 72 columns] but actually it should be [15677 rows x 3 columns] (since all the .csv files have 3 columns and when you sum the rows of data contained altogether it amounts to 15677).

Here is what I have done till now that got me the result I mentioned:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "media/BIWI/*.csv"))))
print(df)
```

Files being used: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19z-OcHRXmTO8VX-Bj8NuOJGJROURLJwt?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `pd.read_csv()` without providing names of columns, the first row of the csv file is used as column headers. In this way, you are losing 24 rows, which leaves 15677-24 = 15653 rows. Since the resulting DataFrames have columns with different names `pd.concat()` produces a DataFrame that contains all these columns (and a lot of `NaN` values). This accounts for 72=3*24 columns. To fix this, you can use `pd.read_csv()` with `names` argument and assign to it the list of column names. Alternatively, you can use `pd.read_csv()` with `header=None` to indicate that the csv files do not have header rows.

Comment: Thank you `header=None` worked well since my data does not have an actual name assigned to its columns. Cheers